# text/template: pattern matches no files: `templates/*.gohtml` exit status 1 in Go

Tags: go, templates

I can't understand what is the problem here. trying to `perse` .gohtml file. Unfortunately, whenever run the program shows this error:

```
template: pattern matches no files: `templates/*.gohtml` exit status 1
```

here is my code snippet of `templateprocess.go`

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    template1, err := template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    template1.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "index.gohtml", nil)
}
```

Go version 1.18.

please help me out.

[image: My file structure is shown below]

Comment: "whenever run the program" How do you run the program?

Comment: go run templateprocess.go

Comment: Unrelated to the error in question, but you should be using the `html/template` package and not `text/template` when dealing with html.

Comment: returning same error.

Comment: I did mention that it's unrelated to your error. That however does not make it any less important. If you use `text/template` for HTML processing your program will be more vulnerable to code injections.

Comment: yes, you did...

Comment: The problem you're seeing is often caused by the fact that you are using a relative path while the executed program's working directory is not what you expect it to be and hence the relative path is not resolved the way you expect it to be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243545/discussion-between-zamaan-and-mkopriva).

Comment: **Never** use go run with filename arguments (unless you know what you are doing).

Comment: The problem is solved. @mkopriva Helped me to find the actual problem.